# How Do I Iterate MySQL Table After SELECT PDO Query Using Positional Placeholders?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ordinarily, I could get each course name in the table by doing this:

```
<?php                        
            
                   // query users' table to retrieve courses' contents
                   $courses = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM courses"); # question marks is used as a place holder
            
                   echo '<option value="">Select a course</option>';
                   foreach ($courses as $row)
                   {
                       echo '<option value=" '. $row["c_name"] .' ">'. $row["c_name"] .'</option>';
                   }
                 
?>
```

Now I want to do the same via PDO prepared statement using positional placeholders, but it doesn't work. The following is what I've tried:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE c_name = ?");
                   if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['c_name'])))
                   {
                      while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
                      {
                         echo '<option value=" '. $row["cid"] .' ">'. $row["c_name"] .'</option>' .
                         '<option value=" '. $row["c_name"] .' " selected="selected">'. $row["c_name"] .'</option>' .
                        '<input type="hidden" name="cid" . value="' . $row["cid"] .'" id="cid"/>';
                      }
                  }
```

Comment: This `SELECT * FROM courses` is just a simple select without any conditions. So I'm not sure why `$stmt->execute([$cid]); `

Answer (score 1):

You're using a prepared statement, but not making use of the placeholders in your query. See the [PHP PDO Prepared Statements documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for more details.

```php
// In the below query, I've added `WHERE id = ?` as your placeholder
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute([$cid]); 
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) # get courses data
{
    ...
}
```

**Edit**:

I may have missed out where you were doing a check on whether `$cid` was posted or not, this should satisfy your requirement:

```php
$cid = $_POST["cid"] ?? NULL;
if (is_null($cid)) {
  $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM courses");
}
else {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE id = ?");
  $stmt->execute([$cid]);
}

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($results as $row) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Your didn't work for me. Only one select option is displayed inside the field, while other options are displayed outside the box. Any idea why the issue occurs?